# Google Drive v3 Folder Creation

Tags: google-api-nodejs-client, velo

I am attempting to integrate the Google API Node.JS module in Wix Code. I have the following code which does create the folder, however, the response does not contain any of the metaData such as the 'id'. I would be grateful for any suggestions on what I am missing.

```
export async function createFolder(folderName) {
const authorizedAuthClient = await createAuthorizedClient();

const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth: authorizedAuthClient });

let fileMetadata = {
    'name': folderName,
    'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',
    parents: ['1pwGKuYsg1ctM-rGXA9Xbor8BEUE3zJRa']
};

let toCreate = {
    resource: fileMetadata,
    fields: 'id'
};

drive.files.create(toCreate, (err, file) => {
    if (err) {
        // Handle error
        console.error(err);
    } else {
        if (file) {
            console.log('Folder ID: ', file.id);
        }
    }
});
```

Thanks,
Peter

Answer (score 0):

If in the current stage, `undefined` is returned, how about this modification?

#### From:

```
console.log('Folder ID: ', file.id);
```

#### To:

```
console.log('Folder ID: ', file.data.id);
```

#### Note:

- This modification supposes that you can use Drive API.

Comment: Thanks @Tanaike. That solved the issue. Where is is documented that the fields are in the 'data' object?

Comment: @Peter G Is there anything that I can do for your question? Although you said ``That solved the issue.``, if my answer was not useful for your situation. I have to apologize and modify it.